# sending mail from xampp using phpmailer :Error occured

Tags: php, email

i am using xampp version 1.8.1 and i have also removed semicolon from `php.ini` file in `extension=php_openssl.dll` but still I am getting this error `stream_socket_enable_crypto(): this stream does not support SSL/crypto` and `Message could not be sent.Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed.`

My php mailer code is:

```
<?php
require 'phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = 'urusername@gmail.com';
$mail->Password = '********';
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->From = 'urusername@gmail.com';
$mail->FromName = 'Example';
$mail->addAddress('receivermail@gmail.com', 'xxxxx');
$mail->addReplyTo('receivermail@gmail.com', 'xxxxxx');
$mail->WordWrap = 50;
$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->Subject = 'Using PHPMailer';
$mail->Body    = 'Hi Iam using PHPMailer library to sent SMTP mail from localhost';
if(!$mail->send()) {
  echo 'Message could not be sent.';
  echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
  exit;
}
echo 'Message has been sent';
?>
```

kindly help me

Answer (score 0):

Set the port to:

```
$mail->Port = 587;
```

Google SMTP uses port 587.

Comment: A little more explanation would help :-)

Comment: i have set the port bt its still giving error-stream_socket_enable_crypto(): this stream does not support SSL/crypto

Comment: Have you restart your xampp?